# Переменные окружения в bashrc

Tags: bash

В bashrc у меня прописано `export NOW="$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M)"`

Как мне сделать так, чтобы переменная устанавливась каждый раз при ображении к ней, а не только при создании терминальной сессии?

Comment: Сделайте функцию или алиас вместо переменной

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11886412/4827341